# NextJS PortableText not receiving content from SanityCMS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity

Using the [NextJS cms-sanity](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/cms-sanity) example code.

The development site is running fine. There are 2 posts in SanityCMS, both with content saved in the content field.

In `studio/schemas/post.js` there is the `content` schema:

```
    {
      name: 'content',
      title: 'Content',
      type: 'array',
      of: [{ type: 'block' }],
    },
```

I've modified [`post-plug.js`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/cms-sanity/components/post-plug.js) to:

```
export default function PostPlug({
  title,
  coverImage,
  date,
  slug,
  content
}) {
  console.log("Content = " + content)
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="mb-5">
        <CoverImage slug={slug} title={title} image={coverImage} />
      </div>
      <h3 className="mb-3 text-2xl leading-snug">
        {title}
      </h3>
      <div className="mb-4 text-lg">
        <Date dateString={date} />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-4 text-lg">
        <PortableText value={content} />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

(by passing `content` and adding the `):

```
  <div className="mb-4 text-lg">
    <PortableText value={content} />
  </div>
```

The `coverImage`, `title`, `date` are displaying, but `<PortableText value={content} />` is not displaying anything.

The `console.log("Content = " + content)` in `PostPlug` outputs: `Content = undefined`, so the PortableText is not receiving content properly, but I can't see where.

`content` is being passed to `PostPlug` I believe.

`more-stories.js` calls `PostPlug`:

```
          <PostPlug
            key={post.slug}
            title={post.title}
            coverImage={post.coverImage}
            date={post.date}
            author={post.author}
            slug={post.slug}
            excerpt={post.excerpt}
            content={post.content}
          />
```

and `landing.js` calls `MoreStories`:

`{morePosts.length > 0 && <MoreStories posts={morePosts} />}`

`pages\index.js` calls `Landing`:

```
import { indexQuery } from '../lib/queries'
import { getClient, overlayDrafts } from '../lib/sanity.server'
import Landing from '../components/landing'

export default function IndexPage({ allPosts, preview }) {
  return <Landing allPosts={allPosts} />
}

export async function getStaticProps({ preview = false }) {
  const allPosts = overlayDrafts(await getClient(preview).fetch(indexQuery))
  return {
    props: { allPosts, preview },
    // If webhooks isn't setup then attempt to re-generate in 1 minute intervals
    revalidate: process.env.SANITY_REVALIDATE_SECRET ? undefined : 60,
  }
}
```

The only real change I've maded is passing `post.content` to `PostPlug` and I believe `post.content` should be passed through `<MoreStories posts={morePosts} />}` (the other `post` data is passed through `<MoreStories posts={morePosts} />}`).

Help appreciated.

#### Additional information

```js
    Operating System:
      Platform: win32
      Arch: x64
      Version: Windows 10 Home
    Binaries:
      Node: 18.16.0
      npm: N/A
      Yarn: N/A
      pnpm: N/A
    Relevant packages:
      next: 13.3.1
      eslint-config-next: N/A
      react: 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0
```